# fazer as somas dos digitos de um mesmo input javascript

Tags: javascript, express.js

Eu to com um exercício para fazer um programa que receba um numero inteiro na entrada, e que soma e imprima a soma dos dígitos da na saída utilizando javascript e express. por exemplo: 12345 = 15

Acontece que eu nunca vi express na vida e não tenho muito costume com javascript, eu preciso só de uma luz, um caminho pra eu poder seguir nele. Uma base que o resto eu consigo desenrolar sozinho.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/sum/:number',(req, res) => {
    const num = req.params.number;
    const str = num.toString().split('').reduce((a,b) => Number(a)+Number(b));
    res.send(str);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Servidor rodando na porta 3000");
})
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Como eu disse na pergunta, eu só precisava de um norte pra seguir. com sua resposta eu vou conseguir procurar melhor na documentação pra achar a resposta. Muito obrigado, de verdade :)